# Play Framework: Gzip compression/decompression of data over WebSocket

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, gzip

Is there a way in Play to pass data compressed with Gzip over WebSocket channels? I read in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/GzipEncoding about GzipFilter. Is there a way to use it with WebSocket?
Besides my server also accepts HTTP requests but I don't want to apply GZIP to them. Is there a way to use Gzip ONLY WITH WebSocket, excluding HTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is some compression extension for websocket connections. (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-tyoshino-hybi-permessage-compression-00).

In some browsers this should be fixed by now and enabled by default (Chrome).
In others (Firefox, WebKit) it is not (yet): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=792831 and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98840

As long as client and server support this there shouldn't be any problem just to enable Gzip.

You can configure when Gzip is used (at least to some degree). For example if you have an JSON API and you also serve normal HTML, you can decide to Gzip only the JSON data:

```
new GzipFilter(shouldGzip = (request, response) =>
  response.headers.get("Content-Type").exists(_.startsWith("application/json")))
```